# Call to a different macro at a certain line

Tags: vba, userform

Is it possible to use the call feature to call a macro at a specific line? I ask as the macro i am coding does this - First it runs half of the code, then based upon user choices it opens up a custom UserForm, and runs the UserForm command buttons. After this I need a command button to go back to the code the line after the UserForm was used. The UserForm works as intended and many different stats calculations can be run. It has a button that returns the user back to the rest of the code, but I can't get that to work.

I have tried using  both GoTo statements and the Call feature (The most promising solution) but have had no success so far.

Comment: I would usually use the GoTo statement in this scenario.  If you post your code we can help you troubleshoot why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve it, I will show one of them.

You can modify your procedure (macro) asking for a value as optional.

```
Sub MyMacro(Optional Answer As Boolean)

   If Answer = True then
       'Do some stuff
   Else
       'Do some stuff
   End If

End Sub
```

As `Answer` is optional you can call your Macro with or without arguments.
Suppose you call your Macro from your user form:

```
Call MyMacro(True)
```

Hope this give you some hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA for this, but I would recommend using the Windows Task Scheduler.  I think that will be a lot better, all things considered.

[image]

[image]

https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard